# Management menu missing options

Tags: theming, navigation

In the Drupal site I inherited, the Admin menu is missing both *Modules* and *Appearance*, making really hard to do anything. I've been tackling this issue periodically for months to no avail.

How can I add *Modules* and *Appearance* back to the Admin menu?

Comment: It's just a menu - you csn go to the admin page for the menu, and add the links you're missing back in

Comment: How do I do that?  Sorry to be dumb.  Do I just "Add New" and Call it Appearance?  Also, if I type in "https://website.org/admin/appearance" it tells me it's members only content that I can't view, but that makes no sense, because I'm every level of Member/Admin.

Comment: That means it's a permissions problem, so adding them manually won't work either. The access has been revoked for those paths, so Drupal will always decline to add them to the menu. It's not unheard of for developers to short-out certain paths so that no one, even user 1, can access them. It's usually when clients insist on having user 1 access, but the devs still want to save them from themselves. Look for custom modules that implement `hook_menu_alter()` and set `access callback` to `false`

Comment: One of the missing pieces is actually "Module" itself...so I can't add Modules?  (Also-- thank you!)

Comment: @Chelsea - Most likely it's an issue in an existing module (so making the update and clearing the cache will fix the missing links - no need to enable a new module or change anything through the Module CMS menu). Do you have access to the file structure to search through the actual module files for hook_menu_alter()s? If you have CMS access only, it might be a little trickier.